# ¿Comó traer datos de dos tablas y mostrarlas en mvvm wpf?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, mvvm

hace un tiempo que ando probando la idea de un desarrollo siguiendo el patrón de MVVM en WPF con c# y he llegado a toparme con un problema y es el como desplegar la información de dos clases relacionadas. Los datos para cargarlas vienen de una base sql server.

MODEL

```
public class Holding
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        public Holding (int _ID, string _Nombre)
        {
            ID = _ID;
            Nombre = _Nombre;
        }
    }
        public class Empresa
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Razon_Social { get; set; }
        public int ID_Holding { get; set; }

        public Empresa(int _ID, string _Razon_Social, int _ID_Holding)
        {
            ID = _ID;
            Razon_Social = _Razon_Social;
            ID_Holding = _ID_Holding;
        }
    }
```

De esta forma en la base aparte esta la relación de que una Empresa pertenece a un Holding pero el holding esta compuesto de varias empresas.

VIEWMODEL

```
public object CntRazonSocial()
    {
        string QryRazonSocial = "SELECT Razon_Social, Holding.Nombre " +
                                "FROM Empresa INNER JOIN Holding ON Empresa.ID_Holding = Holding.Id";
        using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(QryRazonSocial, table.conn))
        {
            table.conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())//Consulta la qryRazonSocial
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
                    empresa.Add(new Empresa(0, reader.GetString(0),0));
                    holding.Add(new Holding(0, reader.GetString(1)));
                }
            }
            table.conn.Close();
        }
        return (empresa);
    }
```

VIEW

```
<ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Razón Social" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Razon_Social}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Holding" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Holding}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
```

VIEW CS

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ClientesConsulta.ItemsSource = (System.Collections.IEnumerable)consulta.CntRazonSocial();
    }
```